# Word for something that can be validated

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word to describe something that can be validated? From *verify* we have *verifiable*. What is the equivalent for *valid* or *validate*?

Obviously *validifiable* is not a word, so what is the alternative?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary doesn't seem to know of a direct equivalent (which doesn't mean none exists, of course). The only derivatives it lists for *validate* are *validated* and *validating*. I think the closest you'll get (apart from something like *provable*, as Mr. Disappointment suggests) is "able to be validated." Or you could just coin *validatable*.

Comment: Validatable has been used in published works; http://www.google.com/search?q=%22validatable%22&hl=en&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1999,cd_max:2000,lr:lang_1en,bkt:b&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ei=nd1ITqjUAs-o8AOWhbm0Bg&ved=0CBIQpwUoAQ&biw=1247&bih=849

Comment: It's not for published work, so I think validatable works fine, and as others have mentioned, it has been used before.

Comment: Context is important, but "checkable" and, to a lesser extent, "testable" are alternatives

Answer (score 2):

The word "validate" comes from Latin "validus" (strong, able) and "dare" (to give).

So if you want to create an adjective expressing possibility, you'd use the "-abilis" suffix  and the word would be "validabilis" in Latin, or "validable" in English.

This would however be a neologism.

Comment: validatable wins here; http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=validatable%2C+validable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: +1 for the link to the good tool. Would you, however, make frequency of use the single reason to choose one alternative over the other? I find it remarkable how much the frequency for "validatable" rose after the 1990s. Would be interesting to find out why :-).

Comment: frequency of use in published works, yes, that is definitively a very good reason to choose one over the other (we are talking established usage in reviewed works; which can be 'wrong' as an exception, but is 'right' as a rule). However, do take ngrams with grain of salt i.e. read up on how it works in regards to punctuation, etc..

Answer (score 2):

Nicholas noted that such a word did not exist, but I looked it up on Wiktionary, [and came up with:](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/validatable)

> That can be validated; that stands up to validation.

So, there is actually such a word, and that should solve the problem.

The alternative would be a phrase:

> able to be validated.

It was actually coined quite recently, and is now used quite a bit:

[image]

Comment: validatable wins here, too - see http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=validatable%2Cvalidable%2Cable+to+be+validated&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: @Unreason, thanks for pointing that out. I had to doublecheck, and found out that some dictionaries actually do list validatable as a valid word.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't or can't use Nicholas' suggestion of *validatable* you might need to resort to a phrase

To say that something is *validatable*, you could say that *validity is verifiable*.

Answer (score 0):

Verify -> Verifiable; Validate -> *Valid*.

That something *can be validated* makes sense in a technical context, when describing input to a process. You could say it's possible to validate a financial model, for example, or that a computer program can validate the value entered in a text field. The financial model and the text field value are *validatable*.

On the other hand, *stands up to validation* and *provable* describe things which can **pass** the validation process, not things which will *fail* it. So they mean the same as *valid*.